# Software to simulate a thesaurus application

Tags: thesaurus

First, please look [here](https://www.freethesaurus.com/look)

I'm planning to make a subject index of an old three volume manuscript text in which a wide variety of subjects (let's call them S1, S2, S3, ..., Si) have been sporadically discussed in relation to one another. As a result of this highly intertwined structure of subjects, it is difficult to have a big picture of the authors thought, and hence follow his viewpoints easily.

For example, at one point, S1, being the main topic, is looked into in relation with S8 and S11 in the first place, and having a slight touch on S12, and then a few pages on, S8 is focused on to S2 and S12 primarily, where S20 has been secondrily alluded to too.

Long story short, just like in the link above, everything is tightly interconnected in different levels of focus. I am looking for a computer software using which I can design this network-like interconnections, probably manually inputting entries (subjects) in different levels of focus, in order to be able to gradually get a big picture of what is related to what in the first look.

Any suggestions, please?